# Can CreateThread interfere with VirtualAlloc usage?

Tags: c++, winapi, virtual-memory

Is it possible for stack space allocated by `CreateThread` to interfere with the usage of `VirtualAlloc`? I can't find any discussion or documentation explaining precisely where stack space is allowed to be allocated...

The following more precisely illustrates my question:

```
uint8_t *baseA = (uint8_t*)VirtualAlloc(NULL,1,MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_NOACCESS);

// Create a thread with the default stack size
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,SomeThreadProc,NULL,NULL,NULL);

// Possibly create even more threads here.

// Can this ever fail in the absence of other allocators? It doesn't here...
uint8_t *baseB = (uint8_t*)VirtualAlloc(NULL,1,MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_NOACCESS);

// Furthermore, in this test, baseB-baseA == 65536 (unless the debugger did something),
// so nothing appeared between baseA and baseB... not even enough space for the
// full 64kb of wastage, as baseA points to 4096 bytes by itself
```

If it *does* in fact use some analogue of `VirtualAlloc`, is there a way to change how Windows allocates stack space in a given process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack space can be allocated anywhere in the address space of the process. There is no documentation on this now and it is unlikely that such documentation will appear in the future.

You can safely assume that creation of the thread and virtual alloc are independent. If this would not be the case, a lot of things would be broken. Allocator cannot give out overlapping address ranges. This is unthinkable. The problem is somewhere else.

The only thing that might look like correlation - amount of memory used and virtual address space fragmentation. In this case the latest request will simply fail.

I worked on a memory analysis utilities.

[image]

This picture shows distribution of the numbers of virtual allocations per size of the allocation.

[image]

This is example of the address space contents for a 32-bit process (blue - committed, magenta - reserved, green is a free memory).

What I write here is based on a real experience.

Comment: +1 for 'This is unthinkable' - the OS would crash so quickly on boot that would probably not even have time to BSOD.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Perhaps "interfere" was to severe a word for this question. All I was asking is, basically, if `CreateThread`, could allocate stack space anywhere -- and you answered that. By "interfere", I was asking if it could fragment the virtual address space of the process (but, now that I think about it, where else would it be able to allocate it?). So, it looks as though random thread allocation would cause fragmentation that no custom allocator could resolve.

Comment: I like the concept "AddrSpaceUtilization" that I introduced myself. This is a ratio of the sum of sizes of all `VirtualAlloc` allocations to the size of the address space itself. My experience with 32-bit processes on Windows show that when this value is less than 85-90% everything works more or less fine. When it exceeds 90%, various problems start to appear.

Answer (score 1):

the windows NT kernel treats memory alloc operations on a high interrupt priority, also in a thread safe manner.

That means only one thread of a process can allocate memory at the same time, which makes all allocation processes thread safe (in theory).
there shouldn't be any interferences between stack allocation and virtual allocation.

Also you should keep in mine that you can allocate 1GB of space but your program still only uses it's 2mb RAM.

That's because windows "pre allocates" virtual space, but it doesen't assign it until you use it (write on it).

Actually the memory management is alot more complicated but for now you can be shure that no allocation operations should interfere, ever, since windows is locking your process onto one core, delaying all other threads alloc requests, as long as allocation is processed. (deadlock)

*EDIT: That also means that allocation and de-allocation is kinda a performance needing process if you allocate millions of small bits. It's always better to allocate/de-allocate larger memory areas, because of this deadlock behavior.